# Could someone point me in the right direction for this proof?

Tags: number-theory

I need to prove that Q (rational numbers) is countable by applying the function $f(m/n) = 2^m3^n$ with $m,n$ being relatively prime numbers.

I honestly have no idea where to start.  Any pointers would be great!

Comment: To prove a set is countable, you need to find an injection from it to the natural numbers. Can you prove $f$ is an injection?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about showing that.  But what I did say is that, since f maps any rational number to a subset of the naturals, and N is a countable set, then so, too, is Q.

Comment: It isn't enough to find a function from $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb N$, even $f(m/n)=1$ is such a function. You need to show that $f(m/n)=f(j/k)\implies m/n=j/k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Injectivity**

$f\left(\dfrac{m_1}{n_1}\right)=f\left(\dfrac{m_2}{n_2}\right) \implies 2^{m_1}3^{n_1}=2^{m_2}3^{n_2}$

***Case 1 $m_1\geq m_2, n_1\leq n_2$***

$\therefore 2^{m_1}3^{n_1}=2^{m_2}3^{n_2} \implies 2^{m_1-m_2}=3^{n_2-n_1} \implies m_1=m_2, \ n_1=n_2$

***Case 2 $m_1\geq m_2, n_1\geq n_2$***

$\therefore 2^{m_1}3^{n_1}=2^{m_2}3^{n_2} \implies \left(2^{m_1-m_2}\right)\left(3^{n_1-n_2}\right)=1 \implies m_1=m_2, \ n_1=n_2$

***Case 3 $m_1\leq m_2, n_1\geq n_2$***

Similar analysis as Case 1.

***Case 4 $m_1\leq m_2, n_1\leq n_2$***

Similar analysis as Case 2.

$\\$

**Surjectivity**

Obvious from the function.

$\therefore f$ is bijective.

Comment: Very good answer, and I was going that route as well, but then I was thinking, "How does this prove that Q is countable?" All we're doing is manipulating a function.  What if we had the function, say $f(m/n)=(2/3)^m3^n$? Then all of this would be bunk since we don't map to the naturals. I'm just unsure of the wording of this problem, I think.

Comment: @Lerbib: To show the bijection from $S=\{2^m3^n:m,n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ let us define the function $g: S \to \mathbb{N}\times  \mathbb{N}$ such that $g(2^m3^n)=(m,n)$. Can you show that $g$ is bijective? If you can, then note that $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $S$ is equipotent with $\mathbb{N}\times  \mathbb{N}$. Hence $\operatorname{card}{\mathbb{N}\times  \mathbb{N}}=\operatorname{card}{S}\leq \operatorname{card}{\mathbb{N}}$. But also note that $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{N}\times  \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $\operatorname{card}{\mathbb{N}} \leq \operatorname{card}{\mathbb{N}\times  \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Oh by gosh by golly. Youre a life saver user!